# define expression on lex doesn't work on some letters

Tags: ubuntu, flex-lexer, lex

I've installed flex in the terminal
**OS: ubuntu 15.10**

```
character [a-z|A-Z]
digit [0-9]
digits {digit}{digit}+
string [{digit}+{character}+{digit}*{character}*]*

%%
{string} printf("string ");
%%
```

after compiling the code, for the input "gg" the output is "string".
for the input "ff" the output is "ff".

I'm compiling the file like this:

```
lex file_name.txt
cc lex.yy.c -o file_name.out
```

if I'm defining the string like this:

```
string ({digit}+{character}+{digit}*{character}*)*
```

it works fine.

what is the reason?
 **I'm not allowed to use C Language**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
string [{digit}+{character}+{digit}*{character}*]*
```

does something different from what you appear to expect.  It is zero-or-more occurrences of the *characters* enclosed within `[` and `]`.  That is, it is equivalent to these simpler patterns:

```
string [{}digit+character+*]*
string [{}digtchare+*]*
```

(barring typos on my part).  It is not the same as this:

```
string ({digit}+{character}+{digit}*{character}*)*
```

which is zero-or-more repetitions of the *patterns* enclosed within `(` and `)`.

Comment: This too: `[a-z|A-Z]`